# How do you enable code splitting in Ant Design Pro?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ant-design-pro

The Ant Design Pro bundle can get quite large before gzip. My simple bundle was a whopping 3.9MB. How do we enable code splitting with Ant Design Pro. I can't seem to find it in the V4 Ant Design Pro's documentation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://github.com/ant-design/ant-design-pro/blob/7effcb09f40bb00f707738f7fdc4d5852a8e2dc9/config/config.ts#L28-L32

Turn umi config `dynamicImport` on.

https://umijs.org/plugin/umi-plugin-react.html#dynamicimport

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I figured it out. Posting here if somebody have the same question since it's not yet documented. Turns out the code-splitting is turned off by default. Look for the `dynamicImport` attribute in the config file and uncomment it.

`config/config.js`

```
const plugins = [
  [
    'umi-plugin-react',
    {
      antd: true,
      dva: {
        hmr: true,
      },
      locale: {
        ...
        baseNavigator: true,
      },
      dynamicImport: {
        loadingComponent: './components/PageLoading/index',
        webpackChunkName: true,
        level: 3,
      },
     ...
    }
  ]
]
```

Comment: Welp, never heard of ant design pro, but glad you figured it out! Looks like they're open source, maybe you could contribute to their documentation or something! :)

Comment: @Andrew Yea that's a good idea! Supposedly Ant Design Pro is what Ant Financial uses for their stack. First time trying the Pro. Pretty neat so far but the bundle size is a bit heavy. Was able to reduce the main JS file from 3.9mb to 1.7mb though :)